# How to check if a user is logged in not using sessions

Tags: php, session, authentication

I've been looking through alot of posts about how to check if a user is logged in or not and most answers that I found where making use of sessions (thats how I understood it anyways:-p)

I included the following code in the php file and it kinda seems to work:

```
<?php
else if ($action =="aboutUs") {
    // opens about us page either in secure or unsecured area depending on login
    session_start();    
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) 
    {
        echo openHTMLsecurearea();  
        echo aboutUs();
        echo closeHTML();
    } else {
        echo openHTML();
        echo aboutUs();
        echo closeHTML();
    }
}
?>
```

Basically if the user is loged-in I want to show the secure area and if not, then it should open the "regular" site.
When I first open the browser (and have deleted my history) it works as it is supposed to (opening regular site when not loged in and then secure area when loged in). However, when I then logout again it should show me the regular site again but it doesn't. It still shows me the secure area page.

I think that's because the same session is still running and therefore the username is still set even though I loged off.

I'm pretty sure that there is a way around but I can't figure it out. The openHTML and openHTMLsecurearea set up is probably not the best solution but it's a little too late to change this now so it would be great if someone could help me with a way around this to ensure the user is actually logged in or not.

Any help is really appreciated thank you very much.

Comment: How exactly are you "logging out"? Perhaps your problem is that the log out doesn't work correctly...? And no, a "log in" is pretty much defined by having a session; a login system without session is somewhere between a kludge and an impossibility.

Comment: where is the first part(s) of if-statement? why session_start is used in if-condition?

Comment: Make sure you are unsetting/destroying the session you create while logging the user in.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do a log-in without sessions, maybe with ip/mac adresses associated with a database? But your problem seems to come from your logout script

Comment: Thank you all so much! It now works perfetly (well it works and thats all I need:-))

Answer (score 0):

First consider using `session_start()` before any single char outside `<?php ?>`
Logout code is simply `<?php session_destroy ?>` and have the same rule as `session_start`: no html before.
And as everybody tells you... **No session, no login system** - or really secureless

Comment: Thank you also! I really just needed this input that the logout was probably not done properly. Didn't even cross my mind but lesson learnt